# Check number of lines returned by bash command

Tags: bash

I have a command similar to this:

```
LIST=$(git log $LAST_REVISION..$HEAD --format="%s" | egrep -o "[A-Z]-[0-9]{1,4}" | sort -u)
```

Now, I need to do something if `$LIST` returned zero or more lines. Here's what I've tried:

```
if [ ! $($LIST | wc -l) -eq 0 ]; then
    echo ">0 lines returned"
else
    echo "0 lines returned"
fi
```

But it throws me an error. What's the correct syntax of doing this (with some details on the syntax used, if possible)?

Comment: Would it be ok to do `[ -z "$LIST" ]`? It checks if the variable is empty or not. See more options in `man test`.

Comment: @TomFenech: He's trying to execute the contents of `$LIST`; that's almost certain to create an error, whether or not `$LIST` is empty.

Comment: Congratulations! You just received [Useless use of `grep | wc -l`](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html#wc) award.

Comment: @anishsane Instead of being ironical, you could have at least come up with a solution to my question. FYI, the `$LIST` is also used in some other parts of the script, therefore I **need** the results from the `grep` command :)

Comment: Sorry, I missed `sort -u` at the end... If `sort -u` was not present, you could directly use `$?`. Anyway, answer by `rici` is probably the best possible approach IMO...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To check whether a variable is empty, use `test -z`, which can be written several ways:

```
test -z "$LIST"

[ -z "$LIST" ]
```

with bash (or many other "modern" shells):

```
[[ -z $LIST ]]
```

I prefer the last one, as long as you're using bash.

Note that what you are doing: `$($LIST | ...)` is to *execute* `$LIST` as a command. That is almost certain to create an error, and guaranteed to do so if `$LIST` is empty.

Comment: And if I need the `if` statement, how to use the preferred solution? It gives my a syntax error if I try to add an `if` statement.

Comment: `if [[ -z $LIST ]]; then`. Note that the whitespace is important.

Comment: That's what I've done and the following errors occured: `syntax error in conditional expression`, `syntax error near ;'`, `if [[ -z $TICKET_LIST ]; then'`

Comment: @AndreiHorak: count your `]`'s. One, two!